# Authorization failed on a fetch request to the Brawl Stars API

Tags: javascript, ajax, fetch-api, bearer-token

I'm trying to send a get request with fetch API to ask the brawl stars API server. I've created an API KEY associated with my IP address. I've tried everything, but I got a 403 response from the server.

Here is my code :

```js
const url = 'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/players/...';
const token = '...';

const headers = new Headers({
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
});

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'default'
};

fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

In the console there is the message:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` because of cors policy.

When I test the request on Insomnia, it works well !

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem with the Brawlstars API a little while back when I was making a Brawlstars command for my Discord bot. I was able to get the API to work however with the following code.

```
        const playerurl = 'https://api.brawlstars.com/v1/players/';

        const getJSON = async url => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        Accept: 'application/json',
                        Authorization: 'Bearer <yourapitoken>',
                    },
                });
                if(!response.ok) {throw new Error(response.statusText);}
                const data = await response.json();
                return data;
            }
            catch(error) {
                return error;
            }
        };

        getJSON(playerurl).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

I hope this works for you!